# Como imprimir con el (for in) por consola un array que contiene varios objetos

Tags: javascript

Lo que quiero es imprimir los paises pero al tratar de hacer de esta manera me dice que esta indefinido

```js
array = [
 {pais: "COLOMBIA", cod: "Co"},
 {pais: "ECUADOR", cod: "Ec"},
 {pais: "ECUADOR BP", cod: "Ec-bp"},
 {pais: "PERU", cod: "Pe"},
 {pais: "PERU DOLARES", cod: "Usd"},
 {pais: "VENEZUELA", cod: "Ve"}
]

for(key in array){
 console.log(`Pais=${key[pais]} `)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creo que el bucle [`for ... in ...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/for...in) no funciona como crees: el valor de key es el índice del array, no el elemento en sí, por lo que necesitas hacer lo siguiente:

```js
array = [
 {pais: "COLOMBIA", cod: "Co"},
 {pais: "ECUADOR", cod: "Ec"},
 {pais: "ECUADOR BP", cod: "Ec-bp"},
 {pais: "PERU", cod: "Pe"},
 {pais: "PERU DOLARES", cod: "Usd"},
 {pais: "VENEZUELA", cod: "Ve"}
]

for(key in array){
 console.log(`Pais=${array[key].pais} `)
}
```

Realmente es más sencillo con [`for ... of...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/for...of) en este caso:

```js
array = [
 {pais: "COLOMBIA", cod: "Co"},
 {pais: "ECUADOR", cod: "Ec"},
 {pais: "ECUADOR BP", cod: "Ec-bp"},
 {pais: "PERU", cod: "Pe"},
 {pais: "PERU DOLARES", cod: "Usd"},
 {pais: "VENEZUELA", cod: "Ve"}
]

for(elem of array){
 console.log(`Pais=${elem.pais}`)
}
```

Otra opción muy similar es el método forEach, existente en los arrays:

```
array.forEach(elem => console.log(`Pais=${elem.pais}`);
```

Comment: a mi parecer , la mejor opción es el for of, por el solo hecho que colocas el nombre del objeto para obtener el resultado que se requiere.

Answer (score 2):

Te recomiendo que uses `forEach` asi:

```js
array = [
 {pais: "COLOMBIA", cod: "Co"},
 {pais: "ECUADOR", cod: "Ec"},
 {pais: "ECUADOR BP", cod: "Ec-bp"},
 {pais: "PERU", cod: "Pe"},
 {pais: "PERU DOLARES", cod: "Usd"},
 {pais: "VENEZUELA", cod: "Ve"}
]

array.forEach(function(key) {
 console.log(`Pais=${key['pais']} `)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ahora si no ponemos mas ES6, la otra opción sería usar `map`, pero ya eso queda a tu criterio:

```js
let array = [
 {pais: "COLOMBIA", cod: "Co"},
 {pais: "ECUADOR", cod: "Ec"},
 {pais: "ECUADOR BP", cod: "Ec-bp"},
 {pais: "PERU", cod: "Pe"},
 {pais: "PERU DOLARES", cod: "Usd"},
 {pais: "VENEZUELA", cod: "Ve"}
]

array.map( item => console.log(`Pais= ${item.pais}`))
```